# Edges connected in strange way?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I'm trying to edit my model but I found that when rotate any edge or move vertex from left/right side, the other side is moving too ? Like there is a mirror but there is not !! I think something is connected between those vertexs but I don't know what is that thing !!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must disable X Mirror and Topology mirror in the
Mesh Options panel.

See the image below.

[image]